# Implement XCode UI Test to verify if a view is changed

Tags: xcode, xctest, ui-testing

I'd like to implement a feature test to verify that my navigation flow is correct. 
A simple example might be from a login page, verify that using valid creadentials, user is redirected to the next page while using invalid credentials user is still "trapped" in the login view.

Which is the best way to verify something like this? I can't understand which XCUIElementQuery I can use to verify that a user is still in the same page or he is moved in the next page... probably the only solution is to check for the availability of a specific element in the view, but it sounds etremelly rough to me.

I've just though that I might use the main view of the controller, leveraging on accessibility identifier. What do you think? in that case how can I query for this specific element? something like `app.views["my_identifier"].exists` ?